# Headers for Content-Security-Policy ,Referrer-Policy and Permissions-Policy on master page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, content-security-policy

I have written three headers for Content-Security-Policy, Referrer-Policy and Permissions-Policy on my master page inside header tag but still it is not identifying on “https://securityheaders.com/”. Please help me for them same.

Headers :

```
<meta http-equiv="Feature-Policy" content="ch-viewport-width *" src="javascript:'';" allow="geolocation 'src'">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'; child-src 'none';" />
<meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are claiming that they are headers, but you are setting meta tags, which are likely not checked by securityheaders.com. Try setting them as response headers instead.

Comment: but these headers we can write in meta tags only? how to set response header?

Comment: You should set them in response headers instead, if possible. You can set them in code, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.addheader?view=netframework-4.8, or in webservers, proxies, .htaccess files etc.

Comment: HalvorSakshaug if i write these response headers in master page code behind ,then it should  take care from there?

Comment: Yes, it should. But likely only when that page is loaded.

Comment: i tried to keep in webconfig, but its giving error like  Unrecognized element 'content-Security-Policy'

Comment: Try <customHeaders><add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="..." /></customHeaders>

Comment: Finally its showing there, so now its confirmed that CSP headers works if we mention inside the config file of <system.webServer><httpProtocol><customHeaders>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251037/discussion-between-vimalsingh-and-halvor-sakshaug).